# OpenGL depth test doesn't work on some computers

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-buffer, depth-testing

My first question here. In my program depth testing works properly on some computers, but it doesn't work on others, objects that are located farther away cover those which are located closer. I called `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` and tried to call `glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);` and as I said, everything works properly on some computers, but the same program doesn't work properly on other computers. How can it be fixed?

Edit: Problem solved. Added these lines before calling
`al_create_display();` and everything works

```
  al_set_new_display_option(  ALLEGRO_COLOR_SIZE,  32,  ALLEGRO_REQUIRE);
  al_set_new_display_option(  ALLEGRO_DEPTH_SIZE,  24,  ALLEGRO_REQUIRE);
  al_set_new_display_option(  ALLEGRO_STENCIL_SIZE,  8,  ALLEGRO_REQUIRE);
  al_set_new_display_option(  ALLEGRO_AUX_BUFFERS,  0,  ALLEGRO_REQUIRE);  
  al_set_new_display_option(  ALLEGRO_SAMPLES,  4,  ALLEGRO_SUGGEST);
```

Comment: You have to ensure that the default framebuffer has a depth buffer. The default framebuffer is created when the OpenGL window and context is initialized.

Comment: @Rabbid76 How can I do this if I'm using immediate mode?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm using Allegro 5, should I call al_set_new_display_option(), or set a display flag?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with Allegro 5. Probably you have to set [`al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_DEPTH_SIZE, ..., ...)`](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_set_new_display_option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to activating the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) ([`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml)), it is important that the current [framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) has a [depth buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test#Depth_buffer).
The [default framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) is created at the time the [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is constructed. The creation of the OpenGL context depends on the OS and windowing library (e.g. [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/), [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/)). Whether a depth buffer is created by default often depends on the system. In general, window libraries provide additional options for explicitly specifying a depth buffer when generating the OpenGL window:

For instance:

- [GLFW - Framebuffer related hints](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints_fb)

  ```cpp
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 24);
  // [...]

  GLFWwindow *wnd = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL window", nullptr, nullptr);
  ```
- [SDL - Using OpenGL With SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html)

  ```cpp
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
  // [...]

  SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, bpp, flags);
  ```
- [SFML - Using OpenGL in a SFML window](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-opengl.php)

  ```cpp
  sf::ContextSettings settings;
  settings.depthBits = 24;
  // [...]

  sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "OpenGL window", sf::Style::Default, settings);
  ```
- [GLUT - `glutInitDisplayMode`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html)

  ```cpp
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
  glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
  ```